# Can Java object class implements Serializable and has Jackson annotation same time?

Tags: java, api, rest, jackson

I developed the below rest api controller and request DTO

DTO class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class reqDto implements Serializable{
    
    @NotNull(message="STATUS cannot be null")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^can$")
    private String status;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{6}$|^$")
    private String rgstrn;
}
```

Controller class:

```
@Path("/foo")
public class controller {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(controller.class);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Service Service;

    
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/foo/bar")
    public Response foo(reqDto reqDto) throws WebApplicationException {

        Response resp = null;

        // validate request dto bean constraints and get error message
        List<String> errMsgs=Validator.validateConstraintViolation(reqDto);

        RespDto resultDto = new RespDto();
        
        // if req dto not validated, return 400
        if (errMsgs.size() > 0) {
            resultDto.setErrorMsg("400", BAD_REQUEST_400, errMsgs);
            resp = Response.status(Integer.parseInt(resultDto.getHttpCode())).entity(resultDto).build();

        } else {
        // call service 
            resultDto = Service.createCase(reqDto);
            
            resultDto.setErrorMsg("200", CREATED_201);
            
            resp = Response.status(Integer.parseInt(resultDto.getHttpCode())).entity(resultDto).build();
            
        }

        return resp;
    }
```

when my reqDto implements Serializable, I got exception NullPointerException from my filter class

when my reqDto does not implement Serializable, I got exception

```
Validator - Invalid request: com.reqDto, constraint violations: [ConstraintViolationImpl{rootBean=com.reqDto@24f5f4ad, propertyPath='status', message='STATUS cannot be null', leafBean=com.reqDto@24f5f4ad, value=null}]
```

when my filter shows payload is `{ "status": "can", "rgstrn": "123456" }`

Comment: I did read up on this related post but not sure what exactly happened to my case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873455/restlet-jackson-works-differently-when-object-implements-serializable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254483/java-class-implementation-for-json-serialized-using-jackson

Comment: please add what is in your DTO class

Comment: Add the complete stack trace of the NullPointerException

Comment: Why are you validating `bp27JLeasCreateCaseReqDto` instead of `reqDto`?

Comment: I realize that whether the class implements Serializable does not matter. I forgot to add getter and setter methods in DTO class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few versions of DTO class, I realize that the exception is caused because getter and setter methods are not created in DTO object.

The Jackson annotations can be applied to objects that  `implement Serializable`